# How do I write the code to print out the sum total of the numbers in a .csv column with hundreds of rows?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .csv file with thankfully only two columns but many rows. Column 1 is a list of dates and column 2 is a list of numbers.
One of the first things I have to do is tell how many months are in the dataset and the second thing is to find the total of all the numbers in column 2 (to then average etc).

i have tried making variables for each column and then using the sum function to no avail.

```
import os
import csv
​
budget_csv = os.path.join(".", "Resources", "budget_data.csv")
​
with open(budget_csv, newline="") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
​
    csv_header = next(csvfile)
    print(f"Header: {csv_header}")

    total = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        totalPnl = total += int(x[1])

    print(totalPnL)
```

I keep getting error messages, invalid syntax += for one.
the two column headers do print out ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong - you're trying to assign the results of `total += int(x[1])` to a variable called `totalPnl`, which doesn't make any sense.

Instead, just increase the `total` variable you already have:

```
import os
import csv
​
budget_csv = os.path.join(".", "Resources", "budget_data.csv")
​
with open(budget_csv, newline="") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
​
    csv_header = next(csvfile)
    print(f"Header: {csv_header}")

    total = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        total += int(x[1])

    print(total)
```